# How to make a child class call a function in All of its children

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I'm having a little problem figuring the best way to make a "child" class to call function in it's children's

Design looks like this:

```
class BaseA():
    a_attr = 'I handle Table'
    def entery_point(self):
         print('Computing Value from %s' % self.a_attr) 
         for child in self._children:  #filling the self._children is where i think need help
             child().entery_point_b() 

class BaseB(A):
    b_attr = 'I handle Fields'
    def entery_point_b(self):
         print('Computing Value from %s and %s' % (self.a_attr,self.b_attr) )

#Now the concrete classes
class A(BaseA):
    a_attr = 'table_name'

class B(BaseB,A):
    b_attr = 'field_name_1'

class BB(BaseB, A):
    b_attr = 'field_name_2'


#another set of concrete classes to handle another table
class A2(BaseA):
    a_attr = 'another_table_name'

class B2(BaseB,A2):
    b_attr = 'another_field_name_1'

class BB2(BaseB, A2):
    b_attr = 'another_field_name_2'

if certain_condition:
    a = A()
    a.entery_point()
else:
    a2 = A2()
    a2.entery_point()
```

What i want to do here is that entery_point() get's executed for A then entery_point_b() for B & BB instance , and the same for the A2 instance (execute entery_point , then B2.entery_point_b() and BB2.entery_point_b() )

How i arrive to do that ?!

---

What i have so far :

```
class BaseA():
    a_attr = 'I handle Table'
    def entery_point(self):
         print('Computing Value from %s' % self.a_attr) 
         for child in self._children:  #This is where i think need help
             child().entery_point_b() 

    def __init__(self):
            for x in self.__class__.__subclasses__():
                if x not in self._children:
                    self._children.append(x)
```

Problem here is that self._children is filled with all of the B,BB *and* B2 , BB2, Basicaly  all classes derived from BaseA , 
What i need is it to be filled with just the classes derived from A (or A2)

I hope the issue is clear enough , i'm open for any questions or criticism to how the flow is going if you do have remarks on it.

Appreciating your help & Thanks in advance

---

The scenario Here:

Those classes form a "framework" that respond to CRUD operation in certain database tables with calculations & stuff to be stored in a cache table.

class BaseA handles the table level (creates a row in the cache table)  , class BaseB handles the field level, ie each BaseB class populate a field in the row we just created with needed values.

Is it time for metaclass master ?!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could shorten this example. It's quite long.

Comment: Just to make sure the i put it as clear as possible.... Thank you you read it to end :)

Comment: I guess you should rather use Delegates to trigger the execution of methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow !!!! i made a horrible mistake , I REALLY apologize !

It's where the self._children get declared.

**The above implementation actually work as expected !**

The problem was in *my code* , not the example above in the question.

Here is the sad trick:

self._children will be filled with ALL the sub classes of BaseA **IF** it's declared on a modular level , not in the init (which is something one shouldn't do).
If it's declared in the **init** (as made 'implicit' in the example above) the flow would actually work as expected .

Thank every one of you for your help !!
@jpmc26 , @Cristian Garcia ,  @jsbueno

really really deep appreciation

Working implementation:

```
class BaseA():
    a_attr = 'I handle Table'
    # _children = [] # & There was the problem...

    def entery_point(self):
         print('Computing Value from %s' % self.a_attr) 
         for child in self._children:  #This is where i think need help
             child().entery_point_b() 

    def __init__(self):
        self._children=[] #the right way
        for x in self.__class__.__subclasses__():
            if x not in self._children:
                self._children.append(x)
class BaseB(A):
    b_attr = 'I handle Fields'
    def entery_point_b(self):
         print('Computing Value from %s and %s' % (self.a_attr,self.b_attr) )

#Now the concrete classes
class A(BaseA):
    a_attr = 'table_name'

class B(BaseB,A):
    b_attr = 'field_name_1'

class BB(BaseB, A):
    b_attr = 'field_name_2'


#another set of concrete classes to handle another table
class A2(BaseA):
    a_attr = 'another_table_name'

class B2(BaseB,A2):
    b_attr = 'another_field_name_1'

class BB2(BaseB, A2):
    b_attr = 'another_field_name_2'

if certain_condition:
    a = A()
    a.entery_point()
else:
    a2 = A2()
    a2.entery_point()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the simplest way to approach the problem. Essentially, you have a list of items, and you want a method to be called on all of them at the same time. This list doesn't sound like a piece of data belonging to the class itself. I think you would find yourself better off if you aggregated your list external to the class and then simply iterator over the list. (You could put this iteration in some other method to be called elsewhere.) This would be a simpler approach (and therefore easier to understand), and it would be simpler to modify in the future (more flexible). (You could add other classes to the list, or you could easily exclude certain instances.)

I generally find that when I start getting into deep class inheritance trees and leveraging the hierarchy this much, it's time to step back and think, "This is too complicated; this class is probably doing too much. How can I do it more simply?"

Comment: the list (self._children) should refer it's children. so , the class can call them to respond when certain events happen. You're saying that such list shall be aggregated away from the class itself ?
It might , but it's more of an API so it's better be a class thing.
I'm with you This is not simple indeed , How would you solve it?
Last, i'm an apprentice who wanna practice some magic :-))

Comment: @radev I would probably revamp my entire design, honestly. I'd definitely eliminate multiple inheritance, and I'd find a way to make it code that I felt like I or someone else wouldn't have to think too hard to understand 6 months from now. Doing something "automagically" sometimes seems like a good idea, but it generally just gets you into trouble when you need to change things later. Burying a detail like this inside the constructor means it's easy to miss that something is going on. Strive to follow the Principle of Least Astonishment and make things obvious.

Comment: @radev Don't get me wrong. I've run into this kind of thing before, but I always end up feeling like I made a mess. I've only recently started to realize that I should *listen **very** carefully* when my inner voice starts telling me that.

Comment: Thank you for your appreciated advice , I'm with you on making things obvious , But This is like an internal API , once it works , it shouldn't get changed "frequently" , but to be built on.
I updated the question with the actual scenario that i need to handle. Thank you again

Comment: So "This" what you were talking about huh ?! :-))

Comment: I think you are confusing "is a" and "has a" relationships making your design overly complex.

Comment: Thank you for the great tip. when i reread about the subject here http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex42.html things turned indeed more clearer..

Answer (score 1):

Oh, your problem was that you where invoking a static field. **EVEN SO**, if your own answer is correct then you are doing something incredibly inefficient. This code

```
def __init__(self):
    self._children=[] #the right way
    for x in self.__class__.__subclasses__():
        if x not in self._children:
            self._children.append(x)
```

actually reduces to

```
def __init__(self):
    self._children = self.__class__.__subclasses__()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** Have class BaseA implement:

```
mainType(self): 
    return 'A'
```

And class BaseB implement:

```
mainType(self): 
    return 'B'
```

And replace the `__init__` function with:

```
def __init__(self):
        for x in self.__class__.__subclasses__():
            if x.mainType() is 'A': self._children.append(x)
```

Or the more elegant filter:

```
def __init__(self):
        self._children = filter( lambda x: x.mainType() is 'A',
                                 self.__class__.__subclasses__() )
```

**Edit:** Because of how multiple inheritance is structured, each subclass will implement the method from the first class it inherits from.

Comment: Thank you , That would work . But i really hope if there is more *magical* way to do it.

Comment: In this new way you will only have to implement mainType on two classes, NOT all of them.

Comment: Thank you @Cristian Garcia , The magic in the question's example actually works as expected and intended, the mistake was in my real code. "magic" newbie mistake i'd claim :$ ,i cleared it out in an answer below (or above). Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just trying to solve what in Python we do through the use of `super`. Using  `super` in your methods you won't need different named methods in A and B - and therefore there is no need to find the "children" and call another version of the method there.

Bear with me:

```
class Base(object):
   def entery_point(self):
      pass

class BaseA(Base):
   def entery_point(self):
      # Do stuff for "Base A" types
      #...
      print ("Executing method at BaseA")
      super(BaseA, self).entery_point()

class BaseB(Base):
   def entery_point(self):
      # Do stuff for "Base B" types
      #...
      print ("Executing method at BaseB")
      super(BaseB, self).entery_point()

class A(BaseA):
    pass

class B(BaseB, A):
    pass
```

(NB.: Your class hierarchy **must** inherit from object in Python 2 - 
and you should do that nayway even if not using super)

The other `Base` is needed so that the method name exists,
and is the uppermost class in the hierarchy with the wanted
method: it does not attempt to call the method
in a superclass.

Example of the above class decorations running:

```
>>> A().entery_point()
Executing method at BaseA
>>> B().entery_point()
Executing method at BaseB
Executing method at BaseA
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer , 
Actually i made a mistake in my code , the question example is actually "valid" , as works as intended .
one thing with the proposed solution "to my case" ,if i understand correctly ,  method at BaseA will get executed multiple times right? , it's needed once and before any other children react.
Thank you again

Comment: If you use "super" as recomended, and shown in this example, it will run exactly once. For the code in the top-most superclass to take effect before the others, you just have to place your  `super` call in the beggning of your methods, rather than at the end as in the example here. (It will still be called last, but the method body for the subclasses will run just when the `super` call returns.